# PHP: regular expression for catching DocBlocks AND corresponding functions definitions from code source

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I need for parse PHP source code to catching existing DocBlocks with belonging functions. Having follow common definition of DocBlock and next to them function:

```
/**
 * Some line of DocBlock
 * ... DocBlock body, one or more lines started with ' * ' ...
 *
 */
[public] [static] function Some_Function (param1, param2, ...) {
```

Note that there may be simple function or class method having some additional keywords `(private, public, ...)`.

Example above can be represents as structure with items:

1. Doc Block body from `'/**'` to `'*/'` (multiline string).
2. Following only one single linebreak (`\r\n` or `\n` depend on OS).
3. Possible one or more tab (`\t`) or space (`\h`) characters from beginning of line (NOT `\s`).
4. Possible one or more keywords `(private, public, ...)` separated by common `[\s]+`
5. Required function name, one word '`Some_Function`' closed by common `[\s]+`
6. Required parenthesis for params '`(param1, param2, ...)`'

I need to catch:

1. Doc Block body from `'/**'` to `'*/'` from item (1) as separated entry/submask in results set.
2. Full string of function definition including items from (4) to (6) as separated entry/submask in results set.
3. Function name from item (5) as separated entry/submask in results set.

And currently I use two preg_match_all expressions to catching them but only in separated way (in two steps):

```
// Catch all docblock definitions.
preg_match_all("!/\*\*.*?\*/!s", $data, $docblocks, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// Catch all function definitions with one linebreak before
// (to identify the end position of previous docblock if exists one).
preg_match_all("/(?:\r\n|\n){1}[\t\h]*(\w+\s+)*function[\s]+(\S+)[\s]*\(.*\)/", $data, $functions, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL);
```

That's right too because I also need to catch unlinked DocBlocks and functions without DocBlocks too.

Next (when required) I link both results by offset positions (using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) in the loop:

```
foreach ($docblocks[0] as &$docblock) {
  // Add new entry to store DockBlock ending offset position
  $docblock[2] = $docblock[1] + strlen($docblock[0]);
  // Lookup for linked function by offset value.
  $function_index = array_search($docblock[2], array_column($functions[0], 1));
  if ($function_index !== FALSE) {
    $docblock[3] = $functions[0][$function_index][1];
  }
}
```

But this is hardly processing. So I still need for third common combined expression described above. I've already tried some many variations of combined expression but always having "greedy" results.

Thanks anybody help me.

Comment: Have you thought of using the Reflection processing in PHP?

Comment: Yes but it required inclusion of PHP code.

Comment: @CodeSmith please provide an array contain a few test strings, then provide your expected output for each of the test cases.  We need a [mcve].